# Common UIToolbar for the required pages - Xcode 8.3

Tags: swift, xcode, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

Please suggest that how we can create common UIToolbar(with bar items) for the required pages?

I know that we can add custom UIBarButtonItem in each view controller.

Comment: Create custom UIToolbar subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use storyboard. First, drag a UIToolBar item to your storyboard.

[image]
Next, set up the location of the tool bar. In my example, I put it on the bottom with padding 0 to left, right and bottom. The height is set to be 44

[image]

Finally, drag as many Bar Button Item as you want to your tool bar, and then add spaces between them. You can either use fixed length spaces, or the flexible ones (which are used in this example) by simply drag them between the bar button items.

[image]